# Is it possible to reverse a MurmurHash in Python with mmh3?

Tags: python, hash, hashtable, hashcode, seq

Here's an example of a murmer hash:

```
>>> import mmh3
>>> seq = "AGTCGCTGA"
>>> seq_hash = mmh3.hash64(seq, seed=0, signed=False)
>>> seq_hash
(12042475613054376161, 7271345330980536087)
```

My main question is if it's possible to reverse a mmh3 hash to get the original sequence?

My secondary question is what's the difference between the two values that are output?

**Is it possible to get back `AGTCGCTGA` from `12042475613054376161`?**

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: @AMC I searched in the `mmh3` documentation, the `sourmash` documentation, and did some Google searches.  I'm not an expert in sequence hashing.

Comment: Can someone explain why this got 2 negative votes?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get back AGTCGCTGA from 12042475613054376161?

This does it in less than a second:

```
from itertools import count, product
import mmh3

for length in count():
    for seq in map(''.join, product('ACGT', repeat=length)):
        seq_hash = mmh3.hash64(seq, seed=0, signed=False)
        if seq_hash[0] == 12042475613054376161:
            print(seq)
```

Answer (score 1):

MurmurHash is not up to cryptographic standards, and it **is** possible to reverse it (or at least to find a sequence that produces the same hash - this may not actually be the sequence that originally produced the hash). You can find a C implementation [here](http://bitsquid.blogspot.com/2011/08/code-snippet-murmur-hash-inverse-pre.html). I'm not aware of any existing publicly-available implementations in Python.

The two values that are output are the two parts of the hash. `hash64` uses the 128-bit version of MurmurHash, so the entire hash of `seq` is the concatenation of the two 64-bit outputs.